# Preferred way to use LruCache: big singleton or many small?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, android-lru-cache

Is it preferred to use a big `LruCache` as a singleton globally in the app where all images are cached or is it preferred to use several smaller `LruCache` at different places in the app?

Comment: It depends on what you need. A big central cache is easier to adjust in size while many small caches may result in cleaner code especially if your caching needs are different. Also non-singleton caches that only exist while (a certain part of) the app is in use can lead to less memory use while (that part of) your app is idle.